# How do I combine values from radio and input box and open an url on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, function

I have two radio options and one input number box and on click of button, I should open url that is combination of those values. The URL ought to be something like salpra.mno.com for button click. I'm familiar with on click function but struggling to combine them.

```html
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="sal1" name="sal" value="075">
    <label for="sal1">001</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="sal2" name="sal" value="076">
    <label for="sal2">100</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="sal3" name="sal" value="077" checked>
    <label for="sal3">101</label>
  </form><br>

 <form>
    <input type="radio" id="pra1" name="pra" value="CS">
    <label for="pra1">CA</label><br>


    <input type="radio" id="pra2" name="pra" value="DP" checked>
    <label for="pra2">DA</label><br>
  </form>

<form>
<input type="number" id="mno" class="mno" name="mno" min="1" max="5555">
</form>
<a href="#" class="mbutt">add</a>
```

Comment: actual output ?

Comment: Why are you using multiple `form` elements? And did you try anything in JavaScript/jQuery so far? Can you share the code?

Comment: It would help if you HTML matched what you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: The result should be something like www.001CA.1234.com

Comment: check @SarojBhattarai answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you change the input value, the href value changes.

```js
$('#tmpForm').children('input').change(function() {
    var sal = $('input[name=sal]:checked').val();
    var pra = $('input[name=pra]:checked').val();
    var mno = $('#mno').val();
    $('.mbutt').attr('href', '//www.' + sal + pra + '.' + mno + '.com');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="tmpForm">
    <input type="radio" id="sal1" name="sal" value="075">
    <label for="sal1">001</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="sal2" name="sal" value="076">
    <label for="sal2">100</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="sal3" name="sal" value="077" checked>
    <label for="sal3">101</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="pra1" name="pra" value="CS">
    <label for="pra1">CA</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="pra2" name="pra" value="DP" checked>
    <label for="pra2">DA</label><br>

    <input type="number" id="mno" class="mno" name="mno" min="1" max="5555">
</form>
<a href="#" class="mbutt">add</a>
```

Comment: This is the exact solution I was looking for. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#add").click(function(){
var sal = $('input[name="sal"]:checked').val();
var pra = $('input[name="pra"]:checked').val();
var mno = $("#mno").val();
alert(sal+pra+"."+mno+"."+"com");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="sal1" name="sal" value="001">
    <label for="sal1">001</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="sal2" name="sal" value="100">
    <label for="sal2">100</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="sal3" name="sal" value="101" checked>
    <label for="sal3">101</label>
  </form><br>

 <form>
    <input type="radio" id="pra1" name="pra" value="CS">
    <label for="pra1">CA</label><br>


    <input type="radio" id="pra2" name="pra" value="DP" checked>
    <label for="pra2">DA</label><br>
  </form>

<form>
<input type="number" id="mno" class="mno" name="mno" min="1" max="5555">
</form>

<input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="ADD"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use form submit to your advantage here.

```js
document.getElementById("urlBuilder").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.action =`https://www.${this.sal.value}.${this.pra.value}.${this.mno.value}.com`
  console.log(this.action);
  //this.submit();
})
```

```html
<form id="urlBuilder" method="get" action="">
    <input type="radio" id="sal1" name="sal" value="075">
    <label for="sal1">001</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="sal2" name="sal" value="076">
    <label for="sal2">100</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="sal3" name="sal" value="077" checked>
    <label for="sal3">101</label>
    <br>


    <input type="radio" id="pra1" name="pra" value="CS">
    <label for="pra1">CA</label><br>


    <input type="radio" id="pra2" name="pra" value="DP" checked>
    <label for="pra2">DA</label><br>

    <input type="number" id="mno" class="mno" name="mno" min="1" max="5555">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```